# Como preparar o conteúdo de um JSON para download?

Tags: javascript, ajax, download

Em uma determinada área do meu site, o usuário pode selecionar algumas linhas do banco de dados para exporta-las para um JSON, após selecionar todas que deseja uma chamada Ajax é feita para obter os dados da mesma, porém dentro do retorno como faço o download da mesma? Por exemplo:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "seleciona-dados.php",
    data:{data: ids},
    success: function(data){
        //data já irá vir em formato JSON pelo PHP, como faço o download do mesmo para um arquivo?
    }
});
```

Comment: Não seria melhor retornar um arquivo do server-side?

Comment: É uma opção também, como nunca fiz, não soube como formular a pergunta, mas estou aberto a outras formas também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "seleciona-dados.php",
        data:{data: ids},
        success: function(data){
          data = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
          var a = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.style = "display: none";
          a.href = 'data:' + data ;
          a.download = "data.json";
          a.click();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Uma vez que o usuário já selecionou as linhas e clicou em "enviar" não posso abrir o link direto, ao invés de adicionar um link?

Comment: editei o codigo

Comment: @FatasyRazer `obj` não existe nesse contexto, coloca `data.nome_do_objecto` para retornar uma propriedade especifica no `json` gerado, ou simplesmente `data` para retornar o `json` formulado pelo servidor.

Comment: osp erro de escrita, `obj` na verdade é `data`,  obrigado por avisar, corrigido !